# c# linq to sql two threads visit the same db, but one is very slow

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, linq, deadlock

I've created two threads in my application and the first one is the main UI thread, which will do the normal job like quering below

```
      var order = db.Orders.Where(x=>x.systemId==id).ToList();
```

the other thread is checking if there is any warning situation to handle, the code is as below:

```
      TransactionOptions transOptions = new TransactionOptions() 
        { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted };
        using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transOptions))
        {
            BathDBDataContext dc = new BathDBDataContext(connectionString);
            var all_menus = dc.Menu.Where(x => x.addAutomatic);
            var menus = all_menus.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
            var orders = dc.Orders.Where(x => menus.Contains(x.menu) && !x.paid && x.deleteEmployee == null);
            var add_menus = orders.Select(x => x.menu).Distinct();
            var ids = orders.Select(x => x.systemId).Distinct();
            foreach (var systemId in ids)
            {
                var seat_orders = orders.Where(x => x.systemId == systemId);
                foreach (var add_menu in add_menus)
                {
                    var add_orders = seat_orders.Where(x => x.menu == add_menu && (x.priceType == null || x.priceType != "stop counting"));
                    if (add_orders.Count() == 0)
                        continue;

                    var max_time = add_orders.Max(x => x.inputTime);
                    var max_order = add_orders.OrderByDescending(x => x.inputTime).FirstOrDefault();
                    //var max_order = add_orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.inputTime == max_time);
                    if (max_order == null || max_order.priceType == "per hour")
                        continue;

                    var the_menu = all_menus.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == add_menu);
                    string menu_time = the_menu.timeLimitHour.ToString() +
                        ":" + the_menu.timeLimitMiniute.ToString() +
                        ":" + the_menu.timeLimitSecond.ToString();
                    TimeSpan tsm = TimeSpan.Parse(menu_time);
                    if (DateTime.Now - max_order.inputTime < tsm)
                        continue;

                    if (the_menu.addType == "by unit")
                    {
                        Orders new_order = new Orders();
                        new_order.menu = max_order.menu;
                        new_order.text = max_order.text;
                        new_order.systemId = systemId;
                        new_order.number = 1;
                        new_order.money = the_menu.price;
                        new_order.technician = max_order.technician;
                        new_order.techType = max_order.techType;
                        new_order.inputTime = DateTime.Now;
                        new_order.inputEmployee = "computer";
                        new_order.paid = false;
                        dc.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(new_order);
                    }
                    else if (the_menu.addType == "by time")
                    {
                        Orders new_order = new Orders();
                        new_order.menu = max_order.menu;
                        new_order.text = max_order.text;
                        new_order.systemId = systemId;
                        new_order.number = 1;
                        new_order.priceType = "per hour";
                        new_order.money = Convert.ToDouble(the_menu.addMoney);
                        new_order.technician = max_order.technician;
                        new_order.techType = max_order.techType;
                        new_order.inputTime = DateTime.Now;
                        new_order.inputEmployee = "computer";
                        new_order.paid = false;
                        dc.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(new_order);
                    }
                }
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
```

in this situation, the query in the main UI thread will be very slow or sometimes doesn't even work.

can  anyone help me with that?

Comment: well, you are right, the code has been updated to be like what u said

Comment: actullay the second thread is running every 5seconds, in this case, the queries in other threads become very slowly! how could i resolve this!

Comment: You shouldn't be doing *any* queries from a UI thread, ever.  Blocking the UI thread to perform a long running operation results in terrible user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but you seem to insert values to Orders in the loop and also trying to use an expression in your main UI.

Besides 5 seconds interval might be short since your LINQ expressions get more complex so that time needed for the calculations increases.

Loading that "BathDBDataContext" might take more time as your database gets new records.
I'd suggest using Cache and increase 5 seconds refresh timer.

Comment: u r right! just before seeing ur comments, i adjusted the inteval to be 20s, and it gets better! thank for all